# HTML Centering Form

Tags: html, css, center

I am having trouble centering the following form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Pages.css">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="Actions/NewUser.jsp">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Create A New User</legend>
        <label for="usr">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="usr" >
        <br>
        <label for="passwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwd" >
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" >
        <br>
        <a href="log__in.html">Already Have An Account?</a>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    background-color: #F5F6CE;
    display: inline;
    padding: 2px;
    border: double #FF0000;
}

legend {
    border: 1px #FF0000;
    font-size: 14pt;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

input [type = "submit"] {
    color: #FF0000;
}

body {
    background-color: #F5F6CE;
}
.center{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
}
```

I run and refresh, but the form is not centered. I am not an HTML developer, I am just having to do a little work for emergency purposes. Is there a way I can get the entire fieldset and form centered?

Comment: You don't use the `center` class anywhere in your markup.

Comment: You need to set a fixed width for form and use "margin: auto;" to center it

Comment: Or, more precisely, `margin: 0 auto;` to get left / right "auto" margins (for centering), and 0 margin top / bottom.

Comment: Additionally, why do you have `display:inline` for the form? Remove that, and add a width of some variety - `width: 800px;` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
    background-color: #F5F6CE;

    text-align:center;
}

fieldset {
    background-color: #F5F6CE;
    display: inline;
    padding: 2px;
    border: double #FF0000;

    text-align:left;
}
```

text-align:center for body tag center your form

http://jsfiddle.net/R6V4E/1/

if you want to center form as vertically and horizontally, give position and size to form as below;

```
form {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:250px;
    height:130px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R6V4E/5/

Comment: Almost working, but can I get it to not only center on the Y axis, but also the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines to your original HTML (`<div align="center">` and `</div>`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Pages.css"> 
    <title>Sign Up</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div align="center">
    <form action="Actions/NewUser.jsp"> 
      <fieldset> 
        <legend>Create A New User</legend> 
        <label for="usr">Username:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="usr" > 
        <br> 
        <label for="passwd">Password:</label> 
        <input type="password" name="passwd" > 
        <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Register" > 
        <br> 
        <a href="log__in.html">Already Have An Account?</a> 
      </fieldset> 
    </form> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will cause the body to center it's contents.

Then, change your `.center` class in your css as follows:

```
.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

This gives it a width (otherwise it will stretch full width), and resets the text-alignment for the form contents.

And finally, change your form tag in your html like so:

```
<form action="Actions/NewUser.jsp" class="center">
```

In order to use your `center` class on the form.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

`form{width:100%;text-align:center;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/marathonman/jzeHu/

Answer (score 0):

Easy... 3 simple things...

1) give you form the class .center e.g:

```
<form action="Actions/NewUser.jsp" class="center">
```

2) remove display: inline; from your css for class .center

3) add a width (lets give it the same width as the field set becomes) e.g:

```
.center{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:239px;
}
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jtLur/

Answer (score -3):

try :

```
<form align="center">everything inside</form>
```

if it doesn't work try float:

```
<form style="float:center;">everything inside</form>
```

if it didnt work try this(last trick up my sleeve):

```
<form style="margin-left:40%;">everything inside</form>
```

Comment: downvote? really? what the heck. im just trying to help and this works

Comment: Why I downvoted: 1. Don't inline styles. 2. `margin-left` won't do what he wants. 3. `center` is not a valid option for `float` as far as I know

Comment: `float` doesn't have a center property.  `margin-left:40%` is not a robust solution. and `align="center` is deprecated.